# Django admin does not call object's save method early enough

Tags: python, django

I have two apps in Django where one app's model (`ScopeItem`) on its instance creation must create an instance of the other app's model as well (`Workflow`); i.e. the `ScopeItem` contains it's workflow.

This works nicely when tried from the shell. Creating a new `ScopeItem` creates a `Workflow` and stores it in the `ScopeItem`. In admin I get an error, that the `workflow` attribute is required. The attribute is not filled in and the model definition requires it to be set. The overwritten `save` method though does this. Hence my question is, how to call `save` before the check in admin happens?

If I pick an existing `Workflow` instance in admin and save (successfully then), then I can see that my `save` method is called later and a new `Workflow` is created and attached to the `ScopeItem` instance. It is just called too late.

I am aware that I could allow empty `workflow` attributes in a `ScopeItem` or merge the `ScopeItem` and the `Workflow` class to avoid the issue with admin. Both would cause trouble later though and I like to avoid such hacks.

Also I do not want to duplicate code in `save_item`. Just calling `save` from there apparently does not cut it.

Here is the code from `scopeitems/models.py`:

```
class ScopeItem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=True)
    workflow = models.ForeignKey(Workflow)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            workflow = Workflow(
                description='ScopeItem %s workflow' % self.title,
                status=Workflow.PENDING)
            workflow.save()
            self.workflow = workflow
        super(ScopeItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And `workflow/models.py`:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Workflow(models.Model):
    PENDING = 0
    APPROVED = 1
    CANCELLED = 2
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (APPROVED, 'Done'),
        (CANCELLED, 'Cancelled'),
    )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4000)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    approval_date = models.DateTimeField('date approved', null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    update_date = models.DateTimeField('date updated')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.creation_date = now()
        self.update_date = now()
        super(Workflow, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In `scopeitems/admin.py` I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import ScopeItem
from workflow.models import Workflow


class ScopeItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'description', 'status')
    list_filter = ('workflow__status', )
    search_fields = ['title', 'description']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()

    def status(self, obj):
        return Workflow.STATUS_CHOICES[obj.workflow.status][1]

admin.site.register(ScopeItem, ScopeItemAdmin)
```

Comment: You should remove the solution part of your question and post it as a separate answer. It's OK to accept your own answer if you'd like.

Comment: Good point. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

As @pcoronel suggested, the `workflow` attribute in `ScopeItem` must have `blank=True` set to get out of the form in the first place.

Overwriting the form's `clean` method as suggested by @hellsgate was also needed to create and store the new `Workflow`.

To prevent code duplication I added a function to `workflow/models.py`:

```
def create_workflow(title="N/A"):
    workflow = Workflow(
        description='ScopeItem %s workflow' % title,
        status=Workflow.PENDING)
    workflow.save()
    return workflow
```

This makes the `ScopeItemAdminForm` look like this:

```
class ScopeItemAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ScopeItem

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ScopeItemAdminForm, self).clean()
        cleaned_data['workflow'] = create_workflow(cleaned_data['title'])
        return cleaned_data
```

Additionally I changed the `save` method in `scopeitems/models.py` to:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        if not self.workflow:
            self.workflow = create_workflow(self.title)
    super(ScopeItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the field `blank=True` on `workflow`.

You said you don't want to allow "empty `workflow` attributes in a `ScopeItem`." Setting `blank=True` is [purely validation-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank). Thus, on the backend `workflow` will still be `NOT NULL`. From the Django docs:

> If a field has blank=True, form validation will **allow entry of an empty value**.

Referring to your example you should be able to use:

```
workflow = models.ForeignKey(Workflow, blank=True)
```

Comment: Doing so gives me a `ValueError` with the message "Cannot assign None: "ScopeItem.workflow" does not allow null values." from `django/db/models/fields/related.py` in __set__, line 335 (Django 1.6.4). From the code and the exception it looks like as if the form tries to save the null value first and does not call `save()` on the instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the field from the form used in the admin, so that it won't be validated.

```
class ScopeItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('workflow',)
        model = ScopeItem

class ScopeItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ScopeItemForm
    ...

admin.site.register(ScopeItem, ScopeItemAdmin)
```

Comment: I need to be able to change the workflow in admin. Otherwise this would work.

Comment: That *is* in the admin.

Comment: Indeed it is. What I tried to write was, that with your suggestion I cannot anymore change the `workflow` attribute of the `ScopeItem` in the Django admin at all. While this is as intended at creation, I like to be able to create attach another existing `Workflow` instance to a `ScopeItem` in the admin form when changing s `ScopeItem`. Unfortunately there seems to be no option to differentiate between creation of an instance and change. Excluding `workflow` just from the create form would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel Roseman's answer is correct as long as you don't need to edit the workflow field in admin at any time.  If you *do* need to edit it then you'll need to write a custom `clean()` method on the admin form.

forms.py

```
class ScopeItemAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ScopeItem

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ScopeItemAdminForm, self).clean()
        if 'pk' not in self.instance:
            workflow = Workflow(
                description='ScopeItem %s workflow' % self.title,
                status=Workflow.PENDING)
            workflow.save()
            self.workflow = workflow
        return cleaned_data
```

admin.py

```
class ScopeItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ScopeItemAdminForm
    ...

admin.site.register(ScopeItem, ScopeItemAdmin)
```

Comment: This almost worked, at least it put me on the right track. Just the block with `if 'pk'...` does not work that way. `self.instance` was empty for me and storing `self.workflow` does not make sense if `self` is the form and not the model. Nevertheless, with just a few changes it is the solution. See my complete answer below.